# Omniauth-facebook Rails 6: Invalid App ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise, omniauth-facebook

I am using `Rails 6.0.0`, `Devise 4.7.1`, and , `omniauth-facebook 5.0.0`.

- I was able to get omniauth to work successfully with twitter via `omniauth-twitter` (which I notice currently happens to use `oauth 1.0` as opposed to `oauth 2.0`).
- I was also able to get omniauth to work successfully with google via `omniauth-google-oauth2` which uses `oauth 2.0`.
- I am not having the same luck with `omniauth-facebook` (which happens to use `oauth 2.0`).

The `initalizers/devise.rb` file is where the main config is in order to specify the `provider` and then the `app_id` and `app_secret` for each provider.  Here is what I have (of course with a placeholder for the real app_id and secret):

```
config.omniauth :facebook, "my-app-id", "my-app-secret-key", scope: "email"
config.omniauth :twitter, "my-app-id", "my-key"
config.omniauth :google_oauth2, "my-client-id", "my-client-seceret"
```

Again, it works just fine with twitter and google.  But when I click the "Sign in With Facebook" link it shows this on facebook:

[image: invalid app id]

I am stumped because I know I entered the `app ID` correctly.  The status of the app is "Live" as opposed to "Development (which required me to provide a Privacy Policy URL).

Since `omniauth-twitter` works, it makes me wonder if something is wrong on the provider end (facebook) or perhaps there is something wrong with the `omniauth-facebook` gem? Of course: I will never rule out that I am missing something obvious.

I am using `https` for my app (`https` now appears to be a requirement in order to use this service from facebook), so that isn't the issue either.

Comment: Can you share the logs for this particular request?

Comment: @sureshprasanna70 unfortunately the logs are not providing any clues.  When I click the `Sign in with Facebook` link it issues a  `GET "/users/auth/facebook"` whihc is followed by `INFO -- omniauth: (facebook) Request phase initiated`.  It then is followed by two `302` requests from my my network.  I should mention: I now got it working with `omniauth-google-oauth2`.

Comment: I'm unable to help you with this very little information.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to solve this by simply changing:

```html
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
    provider :facebook, ENV['APP ID'], ENV['APP SECRET']
end
```

to

```html
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
    provider :facebook, 'APP ID','APP SECRET'
end
```